# Loading files into hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a directory structure with data on a local filesystem. I need to replicate it to Hadoop cluster.

For now I found three ways to do it:

- using "hdfs dfs -put" command
- using hdfs nfs gateway
- mounting my local dir via nfs on each datanode and using distcp

Am I missing any other tools? Which one of these would be the fastest way to make a copy?

Answer (score 0):

I think `hdfs dfs -put` or `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal` would be the simplest way of doing it.

If you have a lot data (many files), you can copy them programmatically.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/home/me/localdirectory/"),   new Path("/me/hadoop/hdfsdir"));
```

Comment: I'm really interested in what would be the _fastest_ way. If I'm copying several files at once, will "dfs -put" be able to copy them in parallel?

Comment: I did little google-ing, I think this the way to go. How much data do you really have?

Comment: I think, programmatically coping the data will be faster. The `hdfs dfs -put` command work as a single thread.